# Search in a text file (with specific pattern)

Tags: java, search, text

The text file looks something like this:

```
    keyword12x:
    =========
    Acon:
    a1
    x2
    z3
    Bcon:
    c1
    e2
    w3
    r4
```

and so on... (always the same sheme and a lot of keywords in the file)

I need a function that I can pass ***keyword12x*** and the signal ***type*** that I'm looking for which searches through the text file and returns the corresponding Acon or Bcon singnals

Exaple declaration:

```
public string searchKey(string keyword, string type){
....
}
```

a call like:

```
search("keyword12x", "Acon")
```

outputs:

```
a1
x2
z3
```

(type = Bcon would obviously give c1, e2, w3, r4)

***EDIT:*** This is what "I have".. (It's not what I want and only for testing porpose)
As you can see it's searching the "keyword12x" line and I'm stuck there.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReadText
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    File file =
      new File("C:\\test.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

    while (sc.hasNextLine()){
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    if(line.contains("keyword12x")){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
  }
}
}
```

***EDIT2:***

```
> step by step "in english":
> 1. go trough lines
> 2. untill you find "keyword12x"
> 3. keep going through lines (from that point !)
> 4. find "Acon:"
> 5. go next line
> 6. start printing out and go next line (loop)
> 7. until line = "Bcon:" appears
> 8. go next line
> 9. start printing out and go next line (loop)
> 10. untill an empty line appears
```

***EDIT3:***
Lets resume: I want to search for a line containing the keyword (with a ':' appended), then (after that line) search for a line containing the given type (also followed by ':') and then gather all following lines up to, but not including a line that ends with ':' or empty line. [summary by @Carlos Heuberger]

Comment: So which part specifically are you stuck on? Have you tried writing this method yourself?

Comment: Yes a lot of attemps, but I am always stuck on the fact that I only can find the actual line "keyword12x".
I can't figure out how to use the line number or sth else (?) to jump to the corresponding signals

Comment: show us what you are already tried
we will not do your homework

Comment: The answer is : you can't. You have to check each lines. That or try to store the line number of your signal somewhere, and skip the X lines to go right to it.

Comment: I edited my post with "what I have". Just didn't think it would be of any use, as I feel compelety stuck with this attempt...

Comment: Try to write it out in English. I don't think your problem is Java related - you need to come up with the steps first, then you can implement it in any language.

Comment: Try using regex thats much easier... docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: so, lets resume: you want to search for a line containing the `keyword` (with a ':' appended), then (after that line) search for a line containing the `type` (also followed by ':') and then gather all following lines up to but not including a line that ends with ':'. [deliberately ignoring the case that the type is not given after the searched keyword]

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger yes this should basically work (only after the b1, b2... part it would gather all following lines up to but not including the empty line)

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Demo
{
static String readLine = "";

String ch ;

static File f = new File("/home/admin1/demoEx");

public String searchKey(String keyword, String type) throws IOException
{
    ch = type.toLowerCase().substring(0, 1);

    BufferedReader b = null;
    try {
        b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Reading file using Buffered Reader");

    while ((readLine = b.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        if(readLine.contains(ch))
        {
            System.out.println(readLine);
        }
    }

    return readLine;
}

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    try {

        String x = (new Demo()).searchKey("keyword12x","Bcon");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

try this one.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you did there and I actually already had a look at Buffered Reading because of performance advantages, but this still doesn't solve my main problem yet because it does not actually use the keyword. And checking the fist letter sadly doesn't work on my real files either. I have to implement it somehow like I wrote it down in my EDIT2 of original post...